# Find multiple string from a given string using regex

Tags: python, regex

```
s = "[(0, '0.105*\"function\" + 0.032*\"program\" + 0.024*\"location\"')]"
```

This is a string I have. How do I separate strings like "function", "program", "location" using regex in python?

I expect the output in terms of list i.e.

```
lst = ['function', 'program', 'location']
```

Comment: Anything wrong with using the regex `function|program|location`?

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for parsing expressions. You want a parser (though a regex-based lexer can be a useful component in that overall architecture).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', s)
['function', 'program', 'location']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` module for that, but - *at least for that sample data you provided* - do not have to use it to get desired output, as just `str` methods will suffice. That is:

```
s = "[(0, '0.105*\"function\" + 0.032*\"program\" + 0.024*\"location\"')]"
lst = [i for i in s.split('"') if i.isalpha()]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['function', 'program', 'location']
```

This code simply `split` `s` at `"` and then pick `str`s which consist solely of alphabetic characters and have length no less than `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = "[(0, '0.105*\"function\" + 0.032*\"program\" + 0.024*\"location\"')]"
groups = re.findall("\"([a-z]+?)\"",s) # get groups of all letters which are between two `"`
print(groups) # -> ['function', 'program', 'location']
```